# Convert java.lang.String to java.sql.Blob using Struts2 and Hibernate Framework

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jakarta-ee, struts2, blob

Is there any way convert the java.lang.String to java.sql.Blob ?

please help me ,this is one of my project requirements Ineed to store user password as Blob format into the Database(oracle10g)

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find this example. I see you use oracle db so this may help

```
package mypackage1;
import java.text.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BlobTest 
{
    public BlobTest()
    { }

    public static void main(String[] args)throws SQLException 
    {
       try {
           DriverManager.registerDriver (new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
           Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:rashmidb", "scott", "tiger");
           PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO BLOBTABLE VALUES (?)");
           oracle.sql.BLOB myBlob = oracle.sql.BLOB.createTemporary(conn, false, oracle.sql.BLOB.DURATION_SESSION);
           String myStr = "To test if the string gets inserted into the blob column";
           byte[] buff = myStr.getBytes();
           myBlob.putBytes(1,buff);
           ps.setBlob(1, myBlob);
           int count = ps.executeUpdate();
           ps.close();
           conn.close(); 
    }
     catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }

}
```

[full article](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=280677)

if you use hibernate look at [this](http://studyjava.org/client-side-scripts/convert-string-to-blob-and-blob-to-string)